# Homeomorphism between $\amalg A_{i}/\sim$ and $A_1\cup\dots\cup A_n$.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we are given $X=A_1\cup\dots\cup A_{n}$ with each $A_{i}$ closed. Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $\amalg A_{i}$ such that $x\sim y$ if $x=y$. Show that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\amalg A_{i}/\sim$.

I have no idea how it is proved. Is there any help?

Comment: As it is, that is only true if all $A_i$ are pariwise disjoint. Also your $\sim$ relation is trivial. Are you missing some assumption here?

Comment: @freakish I am very new to the concept of quotient topology so I completely have no idea how it works. Would you like to explain with no detail missed? Thanks!

Comment: The relationship $x\sim y$ if $x=y$ is "trivial", meaning each equivalence class $[x]_\sim$ is a singleton $[x]_\sim=\{x\}$, and the quotient $X/\sim$ is always homeomorphic to $X$ via $[x]_\sim\mapsto x$, which is well defined because $[x]_\sim$ is a singleton. Continuity requires some work, but it is not hard as well.

Comment: Therefore, in your specific case $\amalg A_{i}/\sim$ is trivially homeomorphic to $\amalg A_{i}$. And thus the question is: is $\amalg A_{i}$ homeomorphic to $X$? But this can happen only when $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint. And so, I think there's something missing in your question, no?